# Bluetooth: Failed to set power on: org.bluez.Error.Failed

Tags: bluetooth

I 've tried to reinstall all the bluetooth modules, but nothing works. Any help is much appreciated.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

rfkill list
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

bluetoothctl

bruce@bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST:~/Downloads$ bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller 48:D2:24:B7:6B:09 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST [default]
[NEW] Device F4:52:2B:63:32:59 Designer Mouse
[bluetooth]# power on
Failed to set power on: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[bluetooth]# exit
[DEL] Controller 48:D2:24:B7:6B:09 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST [default]

dmesg | grep Blue

[    1.224756] usb 3-7: Product: RT Bluetooth Radio
[    8.613918] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    8.613929] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    8.613932] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    8.613934] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    8.613938] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    8.639452] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=1200
[    8.639453] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723a_fw.bin
[   11.538842] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   11.538843] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   11.538847] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   14.743154] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   14.743159] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   14.743163] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  139.366840] Bluetooth: SMP security requested but not available
[ 4945.030914] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=1200
[ 4945.030916] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723a_fw.bin

sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service

Jun 21 17:24:03 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jun 21 17:24:03 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[22213]: Failed to add UUID: Busy (0x0a)
Jun 21 17:24:03 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[22213]: Failed to add UUID: Busy (0x0a)
Jun 21 17:24:03 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[22213]: Failed to add UUID: Busy (0x0a)
Jun 21 17:24:04 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[22213]: Failed to set mode: Busy (0x0a)
Jun 21 17:24:38 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jun 21 17:25:01 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[22213]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Jun 21 17:25:13 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[22213]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Jun 21 17:27:48 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jun 21 17:35:16 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[22213]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)



cat /var/log/syslog | grep blue

Jun 21 16:43:27 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.74 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jun 21 16:43:27 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.74 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jun 21 16:43:27 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST systemd[1]: bluetooth.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
Jun 21 16:43:29 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
Jun 21 16:43:29 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 21 16:43:29 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Error adding Link Loss service
Jun 21 16:43:29 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 21 16:43:29 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: message repeated 2 times: [ Not enough free handles to register service]
Jun 21 16:43:29 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Current Time Service could not be registered
Jun 21 16:43:29 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: gatt-time-server: Input/output error (5)
Jun 21 16:43:29 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 21 16:43:29 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 21 16:43:29 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Jun 21 16:43:29 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Jun 21 16:43:29 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.74 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jun 21 16:43:29 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.74 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jun 21 16:50:38 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST gnome-session[8541]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 55, in wrapper
Jun 21 16:50:38 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST gnome-session[8541]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/GameControllerWakelock.py", line 36, in on_device_property_changed
Jun 21 16:50:38 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x0009 for device F4:52:2B:63:32:59
Jun 21 16:50:38 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x000e for device F4:52:2B:63:32:59
Jun 21 16:50:38 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Error reading Report value: Attribute requires authentication before read/write
Jun 21 16:50:38 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: message repeated 3 times: [ Error reading Report value: Attribute requires authentication before read/write]
Jun 21 16:50:38 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Report Map read failed: Attribute requires authentication before read/write
Jun 21 16:50:38 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Protocol Mode characteristic read failed: Attribute requires authentication before read/write
Jun 21 16:50:38 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: HID Information read failed: Attribute requires authentication before read/write
Jun 21 16:50:38 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Read Report Reference descriptor failed: Attribute requires authentication before read/write
Jun 21 16:50:38 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: message repeated 3 times: [ Read Report Reference descriptor failed: Attribute requires authentication before read/write]
Jun 21 16:50:57 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST gnome-session[8541]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 55, in wrapper
Jun 21 16:50:57 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST gnome-session[8541]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/GameControllerWakelock.py", line 36, in on_device_property_changed
Jun 21 16:51:24 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Jun 21 16:51:40 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Jun 21 16:52:18 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Jun 21 16:57:46 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Jun 21 16:58:43 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.74 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jun 21 16:58:43 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.74 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jun 21 16:58:44 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.172 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jun 21 16:58:44 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.172 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jun 21 17:00:43 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Jun 21 17:04:47 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: ATT bt_io_connect(F4:52:2B:63:32:59): connect: No route to host (113)
Jun 21 17:05:05 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Jun 21 17:05:20 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Jun 21 17:05:42 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Terminating
Jun 21 17:05:42 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.172 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jun 21 17:05:42 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.172 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jun 21 17:05:42 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Stopping SDP server
Jun 21 17:05:42 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[941]: Exit
Jun 21 17:05:42 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST dbus[980]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service'
Jun 21 17:05:42 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Bluetooth daemon 5.37
Jun 21 17:05:42 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST dbus[980]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.bluez'
Jun 21 17:05:42 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Starting SDP server
Jun 21 17:05:42 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Bluetooth management interface 1.13 initialized
Jun 21 17:05:42 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
Jun 21 17:05:42 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 21 17:05:42 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Error adding Link Loss service
Jun 21 17:05:42 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 21 17:05:42 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: message repeated 2 times: [ Not enough free handles to register service]
Jun 21 17:05:42 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Current Time Service could not be registered
Jun 21 17:05:42 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: gatt-time-server: Input/output error (5)
Jun 21 17:05:42 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 21 17:05:42 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 21 17:05:42 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Jun 21 17:05:42 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Jun 21 17:05:42 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.172 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jun 21 17:05:42 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.172 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jun 21 17:05:44 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Loading LTKs timed out for hci0
Jun 21 17:05:52 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Jun 21 17:06:02 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Jun 21 17:06:02 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST dbus[980]: [system] Activating service name='org.blueman.Mechanism' (using servicehelper)
Jun 21 17:06:02 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST org.blueman.Mechanism[980]: Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Jun 21 17:06:02 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST org.blueman.Mechanism[980]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Jun 21 17:06:02 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST org.blueman.Mechanism[980]: Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Jun 21 17:06:02 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST org.blueman.Mechanism[980]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Jun 21 17:06:02 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST blueman-mechanism: Starting blueman-mechanism
Jun 21 17:06:02 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST dbus[980]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.blueman.Mechanism'
Jun 21 17:06:02 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST org.blueman.Mechanism[980]: (blueman-mechanism:9460): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
Jun 21 17:06:02 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST blueman-mechanism: loading Network
Jun 21 17:06:02 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST blueman-mechanism: loading RfKill
Jun 21 17:06:02 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST blueman-mechanism: loading Rfcomm
Jun 21 17:06:02 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST blueman-mechanism: loading Ppp
Jun 21 17:06:13 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Jun 21 17:06:23 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Jun 21 17:06:32 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST blueman-mechanism: Exiting
Jun 21 17:06:57 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.172 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jun 21 17:06:57 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.172 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jun 21 17:06:58 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.192 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jun 21 17:06:58 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.192 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jun 21 17:12:55 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST dbus[980]: [system] Activating service name='org.blueman.Mechanism' (using servicehelper)
Jun 21 17:12:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST org.blueman.Mechanism[980]: Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Jun 21 17:12:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST org.blueman.Mechanism[980]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Jun 21 17:12:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST org.blueman.Mechanism[980]: Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Jun 21 17:12:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST org.blueman.Mechanism[980]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Jun 21 17:12:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST blueman-mechanism: Starting blueman-mechanism
Jun 21 17:12:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST dbus[980]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.blueman.Mechanism'
Jun 21 17:12:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST org.blueman.Mechanism[980]: (blueman-mechanism:24492): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
Jun 21 17:12:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST blueman-mechanism: loading Network
Jun 21 17:12:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST blueman-mechanism: loading RfKill
Jun 21 17:12:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST blueman-mechanism: loading Ppp
Jun 21 17:12:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST blueman-mechanism: loading Rfcomm
Jun 21 17:13:06 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Jun 21 17:13:16 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Jun 21 17:13:26 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST blueman-mechanism: Exiting
Jun 21 17:18:30 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST dbus[980]: [system] Activating service name='org.blueman.Mechanism' (using servicehelper)
Jun 21 17:18:30 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST org.blueman.Mechanism[980]: Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Jun 21 17:18:30 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST org.blueman.Mechanism[980]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Jun 21 17:18:30 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST org.blueman.Mechanism[980]: Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Jun 21 17:18:30 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST org.blueman.Mechanism[980]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Jun 21 17:18:30 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST blueman-mechanism: Starting blueman-mechanism
Jun 21 17:18:30 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST dbus[980]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.blueman.Mechanism'
Jun 21 17:18:30 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST org.blueman.Mechanism[980]: (blueman-mechanism:5016): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
Jun 21 17:18:30 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST blueman-mechanism: loading Network
Jun 21 17:18:30 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST blueman-mechanism: loading RfKill
Jun 21 17:18:30 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST blueman-mechanism: loading Ppp
Jun 21 17:18:30 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST blueman-mechanism: loading Rfcomm
Jun 21 17:18:40 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Jun 21 17:19:00 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST blueman-mechanism: Exiting
Jun 21 17:20:40 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST dbus[980]: [system] Activating service name='org.blueman.Mechanism' (using servicehelper)
Jun 21 17:20:40 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST org.blueman.Mechanism[980]: Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Jun 21 17:20:40 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST org.blueman.Mechanism[980]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Jun 21 17:20:40 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST org.blueman.Mechanism[980]: Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Jun 21 17:20:40 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST org.blueman.Mechanism[980]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Jun 21 17:20:40 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST blueman-mechanism: Starting blueman-mechanism
Jun 21 17:20:40 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST dbus[980]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.blueman.Mechanism'
Jun 21 17:20:40 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST org.blueman.Mechanism[980]: (blueman-mechanism:10741): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
Jun 21 17:20:40 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST blueman-mechanism: loading Network
Jun 21 17:20:40 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST blueman-mechanism: loading RfKill
Jun 21 17:20:40 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST blueman-mechanism: loading Rfcomm
Jun 21 17:20:40 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST blueman-mechanism: loading Ppp
Jun 21 17:20:51 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Jun 21 17:20:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Terminating
Jun 21 17:20:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.192 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jun 21 17:20:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.192 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jun 21 17:20:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Stopping SDP server
Jun 21 17:20:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[8403]: Exit
Jun 21 17:20:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST dbus[980]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service'
Jun 21 17:20:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[10841]: Bluetooth daemon 5.37
Jun 21 17:20:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST dbus[980]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.bluez'
Jun 21 17:20:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[10841]: Starting SDP server
Jun 21 17:20:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[10841]: Bluetooth management interface 1.13 initialized
Jun 21 17:20:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[10841]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
Jun 21 17:20:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[10841]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 21 17:20:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[10841]: Error adding Link Loss service
Jun 21 17:20:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[10841]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 21 17:20:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[10841]: message repeated 2 times: [ Not enough free handles to register service]
Jun 21 17:20:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[10841]: Current Time Service could not be registered
Jun 21 17:20:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[10841]: gatt-time-server: Input/output error (5)
Jun 21 17:20:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[10841]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 21 17:20:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[10841]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 21 17:20:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[10841]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Jun 21 17:20:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[10841]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Jun 21 17:20:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[10841]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.192 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jun 21 17:20:56 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[10841]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.192 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jun 21 17:20:58 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[10841]: Loading LTKs timed out for hci0
Jun 21 17:21:06 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[10841]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Jun 21 17:21:10 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST blueman-mechanism: Exiting
Jun 21 17:21:16 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[10841]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Jun 21 17:22:44 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[10841]: Terminating
Jun 21 17:22:44 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[10841]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.192 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jun 21 17:22:44 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[10841]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.192 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jun 21 17:22:44 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[10841]: Stopping SDP server
Jun 21 17:22:44 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST bluetoothd[10841]: Exit
Jun 21 17:22:44 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST dbus[980]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service'
Jun 21 17:22:44 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST dbus[980]: [system] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'dbus-org.bluez.service': Unit dbus-org.bluez.service not found.
Jun 21 17:22:44 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST dbus[980]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service'
Jun 21 17:22:44 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST dbus[980]: [system] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'dbus-org.bluez.service': Unit dbus-org.bluez.service not found.
Jun 21 17:22:44 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST dbus[980]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service'
Jun 21 17:22:44 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST dbus[980]: [system] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'dbus-org.bluez.service': Unit dbus-org.bluez.service not found.
Jun 21 17:23:25 bruce-W35xSTQ-370ST gnome-session[8541]: (gnome-software:8754): As-WARNING **: failed to rescan: Failed to parse /usr/share/applications/blueman-adapters.desktop.dpkg-new file: cannot process file of type text/plain
```